PHP Unable to Read /home Folder
I am having an issue with a PHP script not being able to read a user's /home folder. This is an issue on a server running AlmaLinux 9.4, my other server running CentOS can read the folder. The error occurs when trying to access using the browser, running from command-line has no issue. Error returned is "Failed to open directory: Permission denied in"
I have tried all the obvious things such as changing the folder's permission to give the apache/apache read permissions. Also I've set that folder's owner to apache/apache. Also tried creating a symlink with the proper user and permissions.
I have disabled selinux and setting ProtectHome = false in both the php82-php-fpm.service and httpd.service.
Has anyone had this issue? Does anyone have other suggestions?
